# sed charachter to leave a match untouched

Tags: sed, wildcard

If I have

`123456red100green
123456bee010yellow
123456usb110orange
123456sos011querty
123456let101bottle`

and I want it to be

`123456red111green
123456bee111yellow
123456usb111orange
123456sos111querty
123456let111bottle`

notice: the first 6 characters don't change,,,,
        the following 6 change,,,,
        also these strings might be anywhere in a file (beginning, end, anywhere)

I want to specify sed to
1)find 123456
2)skip the next three characters
3)replace the next three with 111

The closest I've come to is:
`sed '/s/123456....../123456...111/g'`
I know dots mean anything but I don't know the equivalent on the other side. In short how to command sed to leave characters in a match untouched.
sorry for having been unclear of what I want please bear with me

Comment: see https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions regarding capture groups and backreferences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matching `123456` followed by three characters that are not to be modified, and then replacing the next three characters with `111`:

```
sed 's/\(123456...\).../\1111/g' file
```

The `\( ... \)` captures the part of the string that we don't want to modify. These are re-inserted with `\1`.  The whole matching bit of the line is replaced by "the bit in the `\( ... \)` (i.e. `\1`) followed by `111`".

Comment: I think the second command is close to what I want but I can't anchor it to anything because the string might be anywhere, I don't understand the capture part tho, I've updated the question to clarify

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change each and every zero (as in your examples), then just `sed 's/0/1/g'` would do. Or `sed -e '/^123456/ s/0/1/g'` to do the same on lines starting with `123456`.

But to count characters, as you ask, use `( .. )` to capture the varying parts and `\1` to replace them (using `sed -E`). So:

```
echo 123456abcdefgh | sed -Ee 's/^(123456...).../\1111/'
```

outputs `123456abc111gh`. The `\1` puts back the part matched by `123456...`, the next three ones are literal characters.

(Without `-E`, you'd need `\( .. \)` to group.)

Comment: really sorry this wasn't what I meant, i've updated the question

Comment: @cablewelo2ma, well, I had my fun with the original, wrong interpretation... edited.

Comment: it does it but the grouping is hard to understand the way you did it

Comment: @cablewelo2ma, I'm not sure what you mean, what does what?

Comment: It converts the strings to ones without hurting the lines, the grouping is a bit complicated though, you could add this method to the accepted answer